# Beginner Java : Coding a method to display mode of an array returns default value

Tags: java, arrays

This is a homework project that has had me stumped for quite a while now. 
The prompt is:
The mode of a list of numbers is the number listed most often. Write a program that takes 10 numbers as input and displays the mode of these numbers. Your program should use parallel arrays and a method that takes an array of numbers as a parameter and returns the value that appears most often in the array.

I roughed out some psuedocode for my method but something just isn't clicking.
Here's a rough guideline of what I **want** to do.

Mode method

1. Loop through the input array
2. Check each element to see if it exists in the values array - > this is using the search method below
3. if -1 is returned, then that element is not in the values array so make values[logSize] = to that number and increment the respective frequency[logSize] by one
4. if -1 isnt returned, find the element in the values array that matches and increment the corresponding frequency array index by 1
5. Runs through all values of the frequency array and returns the
   highest one  for now the method just returns one mode(int), but I
       will modify it so that it returns an array of ints (all modes)

   ```
   import java.util.*;

    public class Project_9_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

       int[] bb = {5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5};

       int x = modeMethod(bb);
       System.out.print(x);
    }

    public static int search(int[] x, int y){
       int z = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i<x.length;i++){
           z = x[i];
           if(z == y){
               return z;
           }

       }
       return -1;
    }

    public static int modeMethod(int[] x){
       int[] y = new int[9]; // first array is values
       int[] d = new int[9]; // frequency array
       int logSize = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i ++){
           int z = search(y,x[i]);
           if(z == -1){
               int b = x[logSize];
               y[logSize] = b;
               d[i] += 1;
               logSize++;
           }
           else{
               d[i]++;
           }

       }
       int max = 0;
       for(int i =1; i<d.length; i++){
           if(d[i] > d[i-1]){
               max = d[i];
           }
           else{
               max = d[i-1];
           }
       }
       return max;
     }
    }
   ```

Comment: "something just isn't clicking". when posting a question, be more specific about what problem you are having please. you have posted some code. what part are you stuck on? what is the incorrect behavior it exhibits?

Comment: My apologies, first time posting wasn't certain on everything I needed to do. When I run this program, I receive a value of 1, regardless of the values the array has given the initializer list. So if I enter 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5, the program should be printing 5, but it prints 1. I'm just not sure what part of the method isn't doing its job right.

Comment: There are a lot of errors.  In your first `for` loop, you are using the wrong index several times.  Later, when you try to compute the maximum, you're trying to do it just by comparing adjacent array elements, which isn't right.  Finally, I think your method is supposed to return a value from the input, but it's returning a frequency.

Comment: I think you need to just work on debugging.  If you can't do this with an IDE, you can print things at key points to see if your arrays are being built the way you think they should, and if it's computing the maximum the way you think it should.  A hint: you can use `Arrays.toString()` to print an array (for debugging purposes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added some fixes... and corrected them twice.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Project_9_3 {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] bb = {3,5,4,4,5,4,5,4,3,6,6,6,6,6};  //<<== added input

    int x = modeMethod(bb);
    System.out.print(x);
 }

 public static int search(int[] x, int y){
    int z = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<x.length;i++){
        if(x[i] == y){                              //<<== simplified search
            return i;
        }

    }
    return -1;
 }

 public static int modeMethod(int[] x){
    int[] y = new int[9]; // first array is values
    int[] d = new int[9]; // frequency array
    int logSize = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        int z = search(y,x[i]);
        if(z == -1){
            int b = x[i];
            y[logSize] = b;
            d[logSize] = 1;  //<<== replaced ++ with set to 1
            logSize++;
        }
        else{
            d[z]++;    //<<== used the index returned by search
        }

    }
    int max = 0;  
    for(int i =1; i<d.length; i++){
        if(d[i] > d[max]){
            max = i;          //<<== changed how max is set
        }
    }
    return y[max];  //<<== return value associated with max
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also do not fully understand what you are doing, but I tried to write up few functions that may be of help:

```
//how many numbers of the value 'value' exist in the array?
public static int count(int[] array, int value)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
    {
        if (value == array[index])
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}

 //each index of the frequency array will correspond to
 //the number of times the number at the same index in the original 
 //array was used
public static int[] generateFrequencies(int[] array)
{
    int[] frequencies = new int[array.length];

    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
    {
       frequencies[index] = count(array, array[index]);
    }

    return frequencies;
}

//find the index of the max value
public static int maxIndex(int[] array)
{
    int max = array[0];
    int maxI = 0;

    for (int index = 1; index < array.length; index++)
    {
        if (array[index] > max)
        {
            max = array[index];
            maxI = index;
        }
    }

    return maxI;
}
```

You could then use

```
return array[maxIndex(generateFrequencies(array))];
```

to get the mode, where array is the original array.

Comment: that does a lot of unnecessary counting, and it doesn't meet the requirement to " use parallel arrays "

Answer (score 0):

I added FIXME's to your code:

```
public static int search(int[] x, int y){
   int z = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i<x.length;i++){
       z = x[i];
       if(z == y){
           return z; // FIXME: return index not value
       }
   }
   return -1;
}

public static int modeMethod(int[] x){
   // FIXME:  number of possible values is x.length (10), not 9 
   int[] y = new int[9]; // first array is values
   int[] d = new int[9]; // frequency array
   int logSize = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
       int z = search(y,x[i]);
       if(z == -1){
           int b = x[logSize]; //FIXME: use correct index i
           y[logSize] = b;
           d[i] += 1; //FIXME: use correct index logSize
           logSize++;
       }
       else{
           d[i]++; // FIXME: use correct index z
       }

   }
   int max = 0;
   for(int i =1; i<d.length; i++){ // FIXME: arrays start at index 0
       if(d[i] > d[i-1]){ // FIXME: check if greater than max
           max = d[i];
       }
       else{
           max = d[i-1]; // FIXME: do nothing if less than max
       }
   }
   return max; // FIXME: return y[ at index of max in d ]
 }
```

As a side note, you should really use more descriptive variable names. That is probably one of the reasons leading to your confusion.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. I've gone through and incorporated all of the fixmes, used more descriptive variables as well and as you predicted it cleared up my confusion. If I were to have multiple mode values I would have to return an array instead.
So inside the for loop at the bottom, where I set max = i, I would create and new array with the same size and set modeArray[i] = max; and then return modeArray